# What is the best way to NOT create the object in __init__()

Tags: python, constructor, init

Sometimes, in a class, I'd like `__init__`, when passing to it e.g. wrong parameters, NOT to instantiate the object. A solution may be to raise an exception (which one?). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Raise an exception.** The constructor has a contract with its caller. It promises to create a valid object from valid input. If it can't do that, for example because its input is invalid, it should raise an exception to indicate its failure.

If `__init__()` exits successfully, i.e. without raising an exception, that means by definition that the object has been successfully constructed and initialized.

Contrived example of how to do it:

```
class Bacon:
    def __init__(self, deliciousness=1000):
        if deliciousness < 100:
            raise InvalidArgumentException('Bacon is always delicous')

        self.deliciousness = deliciousness
```

Comment: Technically speaking, the object is already created by the time `__init__` is called. But raising an exception is still the right thing to do; it is the *constructor* (e.g. `object.__new__`) that produces the new instance object, calling on `__init__` to initialize that object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! I changed the wording of the answer.